# Rxjava: multible Observables, execute the next observable if only the previous failed

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a case when I have multiple observables, each observable has its own implementation, they may be with the same type, or different I didn't decide know yet, but let's assume it they're the same type.

```
Observable<String> source1;
Observable<String> source2;
Observable<String> source3;
Observable<String> source4;
```

what I need to do now is to execute only one of them, so stream only move to the next observable if the previous one failed.

**Some potential solutions**:

- the onErrorResumeNext() which it may be good if they're only two
  observables, but in my case here, if I need to change the order of execution it will hard to update each observable.
- there is the combineLatest but I don't know if it behaves the way I
  described, or what modification to make work as I need.

how to achieve something like this and if they're  with different types, what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is better way to do it, but I would just use `onErrorResumeNext()` with the help of some methods for making it flexible:

```
Observable<String> buildObservable(Observable<String> obs, Observable<String>... subsequentObservables) {
    Observable<String> observable = obs;
    for (int i = 0; i < subsequentObservables.length; i++) {
        observable = concatErrorObservable(observable, subsequentObservables[i]);
    }

    return observable;
}
```

where `concatErrorObservable` is:

```
Observable<String> concatErrorObservable(Observable<String> observable, Observable<String> observable2) {
        return observable.onErrorResumeNext(observable2);
    }
```

So you just need to provide the list of `Observable` to the `buildObservable` method. For example:

```
buildObservable(Observable.error(new Throwable("error!!")), 
    Observable.just("observable2"), 
    Observable.just("observable3"))
.subscribe(s -> Log.d(TAG, "result: " + s));
```

will print `observable2` (in the logcat) because the first observable throws an error.

About the different types, you probably need a different `map` for each `Observable`, because I think your consumer (observer) will just expect one type of emitted data.

Comment: I tried this solution and it works fine, however I had to change the argument from varargs to List.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a combined observable using `onErrorResumeNext` and `reduce` like this:

```
Observable<String> buildObservable(List<Observable<String>> observables) {
    return Observable.fromIterable(observables)
            .reduce(Observable::onErrorResumeNext)
            .flatMapObservable(obs -> obs);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
To explain further, if you call the method with a list `[o1, o2, o3]`, then

- the `fromIterable` will return a *higher-level* observable equivalent to **`just(o1, o2, o3)`**
- the `reduce` will combine the elements of this observable, sequentially calling `onErrorResumeNext()` with each element, like this:

  ```
  o1 -> o1.onErrorResumeNext(o2) -> o1.onErrorResumeNext(o2).onErrorResumeNext(o3),
  ```

  resulting in a still "higher level" 1-element observable that is equivalent to **`just(o1.onErrorResumeNext(o2).onErrorResumeNext(o3))`**.
- the `flatMapObservable()` line will replace this 1-element observable with its one and only element itself, which is **`o1.onErrorResumeNext(o2).onErrorResumeNext(o3)`** (without the `just()`).

This result implements the fallback mechanism you need.

Comment: the problem with this solution, is in reduce() line, how to make the next observable a fallback to the previous one. could you explain more?

Comment: I updated the answer based on your comment, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, actually I used a mix solution from both answers.